# Find li whose children a element has empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example HTML

```
<li class= "View">
<a><span>Red</span></a>
</li>
<li class= "View">
<a><span>Orange</span></a>
</li>

<li class= "View">
<a><span>Green</span></a>
</li>
<li class= "View NotView">
<a><span>Green not view</span></a>
</li>
<li class= "View">
<a><span></span></a>
</li>
<li class= "View">
<a><span>Brown</span></a>
</li>
```

I want to select all li tags which has class View and do not have class NotView
And span tag under li tag cannot be empty so I need output to be

```
Red
Orange
Green
Brown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-class selector to avoid element with a certain class and then filter out empty element using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```js
console.log(
  $('li.View:not(.NotView)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim().length
  }).map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim();
  }).get()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Red</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Orange</span></a>
  </li>

  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Green</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View NotView">
    <a><span>Green not view</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Brown</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

With [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-class selector instead of [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```js
console.log(
  $('li.View:not(.NotView):not(:has(:empty))').map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim();
  }).get()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Red</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Orange</span></a>
  </li>

  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Green</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View NotView">
    <a><span>Green not view</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Brown</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

So it is an class selector and a has selector that checks for empty.

```js
var lis = $("li").not("li.NotView, li:has(span:empty)");
console.log(lis);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Red</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Orange</span></a>
  </li>

  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Green</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View NotView">
    <a><span>Green not view</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="View">
    <a><span>Brown</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That isn't good thing for console show and cause user confused. I think that is better to change color of selected li.

Comment: @Mohammad a) I think that code was intended for demo, not production (you wouldn't log it in production in all likelihood) and b) most users probably aren't looking in their console in any case.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, what if I want span to contain some specific text. My span contains &nbsp; when it is empty?

Comment: Than if that is the case, you would need to use a filter method like the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector like this

```
$('li.View').not('.NotView').has('a span:not(:empty)')
```

and then you can use  `map()` to get text in array or something similar.

```js
var arr = $('li.View').not('.NotView').has('a span:not(:empty)').map(function() {
  return $(this).find('a span').text();
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="View">
  <a><span>Red</span></a>
</li>
<li class="View">
  <a><span>Orange</span></a>
</li>

<li class="View">
  <a><span>Green</span></a>
</li>
<li class="View NotView">
  <a><span>Green not view</span></a>
</li>
<li class="View">
  <a>asdf<span></span></a>
</li>
<li class="View">
  <a><span>Brown</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.View").not('.NotView').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('span').html().trim() !== '') {
            console.log($(this).find('span').html());
        }
    });
});
```